# Quick Action using Visualforce - modal dialog width

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning, css, quickaction

When you use Visualforce page as Quick Action and modal popup window opens - it occupies 50% of container width. According to [Create Object-Specific Quick Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_object_specific_actions.htm&type=5) article

> For a Custom Visualforce action, select the Visualforce page, and then
>   specify the height of the action window. The width is fixed.

Is there a "best practice" way to adjust width in this case using some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width is fixed. You're meant to create a responsive design that fits in the margins. No css or JavaScript you write can change this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Is the same formally possible when you use Lightning Component for Quick Action, not Visualforce page?

Comment: @Victor The width of a Quick Action is also fixed, so you should be using SLDS to create responsive layouts. Remember that a Quick Action will appear on phones, tablets, and the desktop, so you need to have a responsive UI design that will fit all three device profiles.

Comment: Thank you, your answers and comments are very useful. I got it about responsive UI of content displayed in Quick Action modal. I'm just concerned about what I see here https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals. There is written about large modals occupying 90% of width. Isn't it something we can use in Lightning Component to make Quick Action modal purposely occupying 90% of width? If no, I just wonder what are they talking about here?

Comment: @Victor It's something that they use for recordEdit, etc. The quick actions always use the smaller 50% version.

Comment: Thanks. Adding related idea here, so people coming and reading this can vote and hopefully we'll see this feature available soon https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E6ocQAC

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it by doing some CSS adjustments. Check the following blog which has an example with source code.

[How to recreate modal component for force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader ( Showing quick action same as Lightning Experience Standard modal )](https://sfcure.com/2018/04/01/how-to-recreate-modal-component-for-forcelightningquickactionwithoutheader/)